# DatePicker onDataSet is not working properly

Tags: android

i created my own DatePicker for now the date picking is working but i would like to limit it that the user will not have the ability th choose a date that is before the current date.
in the following code when i choose the date 11.11.15 i get the following print

```
 D/this date﹕ 2015 11 11
 D/this date﹕ 2015 11 9
```

but still is not getting inside my if :

```
if(this.year < year || this.month < monthOfYear || this.day < dayOfMonth)
```

this is the all code:

```
  package com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Utilities;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.InterfacesAndConstants.OnCompleteListener;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by matant on 9/10/2015.
 */
public class DatePicker extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private OnCompleteListener mListener;
    private int year,month,day;
    private  Calendar cal;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try{
            mListener =  (OnCompleteListener) getTargetFragment();
        }catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            Log.d("Class casting Error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Date today = new Date();
          cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(today);
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH,-6);
        long minDate = cal.getTime().getTime();
        year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
         month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
         day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog pickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        pickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate);
        return pickerDialog;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Log.d("Calendar",String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)+"/"+String.valueOf(monthOfYear)+"/"+String.valueOf(year));
        {
            Log.d("this date",String.valueOf(this.year)+" "+String.valueOf(this.month)+" "+String.valueOf(this.day));
            Log.d("this date",String.valueOf(year)+" "+String.valueOf(monthOfYear)+" "+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth));

            if(this.year < year || this.month < monthOfYear || this.day < dayOfMonth)
            {
                Log.d("date no valid","wrong date");
                mListener.onComplete("Date_not_valid","Please insert a valid date!");
            }else{
                Log.d("date  valid","date");
                mListener.onComplete("date",String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)+"/"+String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)+"/"+String.valueOf(year));
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DatePicker has a function to set the minimum date provided.

[DatePicker setMinDate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate(long))

Try using this inside your dialog fragment.

Comment: where i should use this function? inside the onCreatedialog or in onDataSet?

Comment: i had also mistake in the if condition its should be "this.day > dayOfMonth"